# Не импортируется библиотека Folium Python 2.7

Tags: python, folium

Я пытаюсь начать работу с библиотекой Folium на Python 2.7, установил библиотеку через `pip install folium` установилось без проблем, но при попытке импорта возникает ошибка

```
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_map.py", line 1, in <module>
    import folium
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\folium\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    import branca
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\branca\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    import branca.colormap as colormap
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\branca\colormap.py", line 15, in <module>
    from branca.element import ENV, Figure, JavascriptLink, MacroElement
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\branca\element.py", line 13, in <module>
    from urllib.request import urlopen
ImportError: No module named request

Process finished with exit code 1
`
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как это исправить.

Comment: установить `requests` таким же образом?

Comment: Как удалось установить branca? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61139405/cant-install-folium-on-linux-mint-with-python-2-7-because-of-error-with-branca ?

Comment: branca и requests установлены, вот список всех установленных пакетов:
branca==0.4.1
certifi==2021.10.8
chardet==4.0.0
codegen==1.0
Django==1.4
folium==0.8.3
idna==2.10
Jinja2==2.11.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.16.6
patterns==0.3
pytz==2021.3
requests==2.27.1
six==1.16.0
urllib3==1.26.9

Comment: Замените branco на более старую. `pip install branca<0.4.0`.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: а почему python 2.7?

Comment: @strawdog, производственная необходимость